# Add data attribute to all images under a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a lightbox that requires a specific tag inside the link. I don't really want to edit every post so I'm trying to do this automatically using jquery.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="imagelink.png">Image</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

// Scan classes
$('.wrapper a').each(function(){

    // Apply tag
    $(this).parent().attr('data-lity');

});
});
```

Result should be

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href="imagelink.png" data-lity>Image</a>
</div>
```

JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c2RvG/31/

Comment: .attr with one argument **gets** the current value of the selected attribute, you need two arguments to **set**

Comment: what is the purpose of a data attribute with no data? The whole point of data attributes is to store relevant data into a storage 'container' within an element. it is pointless setting the name of a data attrbute (effectiely nameing the container) without setting any data value to that atttribute / container

Comment: I'm reading the documentation of this plugin and it seems like it's supposed to be like that. For reference http://sorgalla.com/lity/ and here's a working version  http://jsfiddle.net/c2RvG/33/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do a trick

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Scan the webpage for all class names of 'thumb' that is seen.

    $('.wrapper a').attr('data-lity', '');

});
```

[image]

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q1hdvnvr/)

Answer (score 3):

script

```
$('.wrapper a').attr('data-lity', '');
```

You don't need to iterate. Jquery does it for you. Just set the attribute.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

 // Scan classes
   $('.wrapper a').each(function(){

 // Apply tag
    $(this).parent().attr('data-lity','');

  });
 });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the data attribute be on the a not the parent of the a  which is the .wrapper? ( $(this).attr('data-lity','');